# solve differential equation $x y'=y+\sqrt{x^2-y^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I used $y=vx$ and I got $x^2v'=\sqrt{x^2-v^2x^2}$, normally we write absolute value of $x$ when we extract $x^2$ from the square root, but I do not see anyone doing this at all, why?

Comment: There should be an absolute value in theory. Or you can consider cases, either way.

Comment: I think this is because the equation already has issues at $x = 0,$ so they're just solving under the assumption $x > 0.$